# Laravel:edit and update:: how to update the post in this situation?

Tags: laravel-8

I'd like to update the post but when I edit the article and update, seems like its adding the post.
How can I update properly...

[what I tried]

・ $books ->save(); to  $books ->update();
if i changed here it looks like not adding post as well as update

・emit[$books = new Book;]
→it comes with an error

my form is using Laravel collective HTML

```js
public function edit($book_id)
    {
        $books = Book::find($book_id);
        $books = Book::pluck('name','name');
        return view('front.book.edit',[
            'books' => $books
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request,$book_id)
    {
        $books = Book::find($book_id);
        $name = $request ->name;
        $title = $request ->title;
        $comments = $request ->comments;

        $books = new Book;
        $books -> name =$name;
        $books -> title=$title;
        $books -> comments=$comments;

        $books ->save();

        return redirect()->route('home.books')->with('message','修正しました');
    }
```

```css
Route::put('/books/update/{book_id}',  [BookController::class, 'update'])->name('book.update');
Route::delete('/books/destroy/{book_id}', [BookController::class, 'destroy'])->name('book.destroy');
Route::get('/books/edit/{book_id}', [BookController::class, 'edit'])->name('book.edit');
```

```html
{!! Form::open(['route' => ['book.update','book_id'], 'method' => 'post']) !!}
{{ method_field('put') }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see in your `update` method, you need to remove or comment this code

`$books = new Book;`

Here's what your update method should look like:

```
public function update(Request $request,$book_id){
        $books = Book::find($book_id);
        $name = $request ->name;
        $title = $request ->title;
        $comments = $request ->comments;

        // $books = new Book;
        $books -> name =$name;
        $books -> title=$title;
        $books -> comments=$comments;

        $books ->save();

        return redirect()->route('home.books')->with('message','修正しました');
    }
```

By leaving what you had there initially, you were always creating a new instance for your `Book` model, and that will keep creating a new record

Also, you need to look back at your Form action here

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => ['book.update','book_id'], 'method' => 'post']) !!}
```

The `'book_id'` you are passing is actually supposed to be the real id of the book you wish to update.

So it should be something like this:

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => ['book.update', $books->id], 'method' => 'post']) !!}
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for answering my question. I tried to comment out // $books = new Book; but, it comes with an errpr [Attempt to assign property "name" on null]....

Comment: Yes, i saw that coming. It means that what you have here `$books = Book::find($book_id);` has no result.
I will suggest you verify what the value of `$book_id` is, and check in your database, if that `id` is truly present in the database table

Comment: I'll add an edit to my answer now, to try to explain better, please let me know if the edited answer helps

Comment: Thank you very much!!!! I  I'll check the database !!

Comment: You are welcome, also check my edit, showing you a mistake i think you made in your Form action, and remember to please mark as answer if i helped you solve the problem 

Comment: I'm glad I could help, and thank you for marking as answer. I wish you would also help upvote the answer. 

Answer (score 0):

I can do it using my code.

```
public function update($book_id)
{
 books ::find($book_id)->update([
            'name'=>$name,
            'title'=>$title,
            'comments'=>$comments,              
        ]);
 return redirect()->route('home.books')->with('message','修正しました');
}

Route::get('/books/update/{book_id}',  [BookController::class, 'update'])->name('book.update');
```

hope it helps you

Comment: hello, thank you for helping me. i tried to use your code but it says[ Call to a member function update() on null] ... also, im trying to pass the value of book_id but still comes with an error....[Attempt to assign property "name" on null]